# Create multiple Folders on server then create network share for each as well

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, for-loop

I am trying loop through a text file with a list of folder names I would like to create. Then also create a network share to the folder as well.

I am able to create the folder but I am getting stuck on creating the network share.

```
$folder ='\\networkserver\D$'  #Root Directory to place the New folders in.
$routes = get-content 'C:\uncroutes.txt'



foreach ($routes in $routes) {
    $newpath = Join-Path "$folder\" -ChildPath $routes
    New-Item $newpath -type Directory
    foreach ($newpath in $newpath) {
        New-SmbShare -Name $newpath -Path $folder -FullAccess Administrator
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

> New-SmbShare -Name $newpath -Path $folder -FullAccess Adminis ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_SMBShare:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMBShare) [New-SmbShare], CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 5,New-SmbShare

Got it working with Help from @Adminofthings. Here is the working code.

```
    $folder ='\\networkserver\D$'  #Root Directory to place the New folders in.
$routes = get-content 'C:\uncroutes.txt' #list of folder Names


foreach ($route in $routes) {
    $newpath = Join-Path "$folder\" -ChildPath $route
    New-Item $newpath -type Directory
    foreach ($ShareName in $ShareNames) {
        $ShareName = ($route | sls -pattern "([0-9a-zA-Z-_ ]+)$").matches.value
        $serverpath = "d:\$route"
        New-SmbShare -Name $ShareName -Path $serverpath -FullAccess Administrator
    }
}
```

Comment: You also chose the very same variable in the foreach for the current item and the collection - change to the singular for the current item.

Comment: `-name` needs to take the folder name rather than a path, which you will need to derive from `$route` in your foreach loop. The `-childpath` parameter needs to take in `$route` rather than `$routes`.

Comment: I feel like we will need to know the structure of the uncroutes.txt file to be able to help any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume correctly about uncroutes.txt and say that it contains a unc path on each line, then you can get the share name by using something like the code below:

```
$ShareName = ($route | sls -pattern "([0-9a-zA-Z-_ ]+)$").matches.value
```

Then pass `$ShareName` into your `-name` parameter.

Comment: If your share names are expected to have characters other than alphanumeric, underscores, spaces, and hyphens, you will need to add those to the regex pattern.

Comment: Ok, thank you added that to the nested loop and made another variable for the server path. It is working now.